# Error while annotation processing with Kapt and Dagger2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2, kapt

I have spent some time with my error but without any positive result so I maybe someone can help. 
I have 3 modules in my project : app (android), data, domain - both pure kotlin. All DI is in app module.

ApplicationComponent & ApplicationModule:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class,
        NavigatorModule::class,
        RepositoryModule::class,
        FirebaseModule::class,
        SchedulerModule::class,
        UseCaseModule::class))
interface ApplicationComponent {
    fun injectApplication(application: Application)

    fun loginSubComponent() : LoginSubComponent
}

@Module
class ApplicationModule(private val application: Application) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApplication() = application
}

@Module
class UseCaseModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginAccountUseCase(scheduler: ComposeScheduler, repository: AccountRepository) = LoginAccountUseCase(scheduler, repository)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLoginAnonymousUseCase(scheduler: ComposeScheduler, repository: AccountRepository) = LoginAnonymousUseCase(scheduler, repository)

}
```

LoginSubComponent & LoginModule:

```
@ActivityScope
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(LoginModule::class))
interface LoginSubComponent {
    fun inject(activity: LoginActivity)
}

@Module
class LoginModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    fun provideLoginPresenter(loginAccountUseCase: LoginAccountUseCase, loginAnonymousUseCase: LoginAnonymousUseCase)
            = LoginPresenter(loginAccountUseCase, loginAnonymousUseCase)
}
```

and I am injecting it like below in LoginActivity:

```
@Inject
lateinit var navigator: Navigator

@Inject <- This inject causes issue
lateinit var presenter: LoginPresenter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    appComponent.loginSubComponent().inject(this)
    initView()
    .....
}
```

This configuration causes error:

```
/home/user/projects/xxx/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/xxx/presentation/di/component/ApplicationComponent.java:6: error: [xxx.presentation.di.component.LoginSubComponent.inject(xxx.presentation.login.LoginActivity)] xxx.presentation.login.LoginPresenter cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
e: 

e: public abstract interface ApplicationComponent {
e:                 ^
e:       xxx.presentation.login.LoginPresenter is injected at
e:           xxx.presentation.login.LoginActivity.presenter
e:       xxx.presentation.login.LoginActivity is injected at
e:           xxx.presentation.di.component.LoginSubComponent.inject(activity)
e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to analyze: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.analyzer.AnalysisResult.throwIfError(AnalysisResult.kt:57)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:158)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:107)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:92)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:386)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$compile$1$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:892)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl$doCompile$$inlined$ifAlive$lambda$2.invoke(CompileServiceImpl.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.DummyProfiler.withMeasure(PerfUtils.kt:137)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.checkedCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:919)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.doCompile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:891)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:385)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor88.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.diagnostic.KaptError: Error while annotation processing
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:90)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.runAnnotationProcessing(Kapt3Extension.kt:205)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:166)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:82)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:83)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:376)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:67)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:96)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:367)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:132)
    ... 29 more
```

I can not use DI now because of this error and I am almost sure that Java version should work fine with this configuration. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Didn't you forget the LoginModule() on your component?
`appComponent.loginSubComponent().loginModule(LoginModule()).inject(this)`

Comment: I have tried also version like above but without any success... As far as I know dagger will create missing dependencies from LoginModule out of the box, so my version is also correct

Comment: Does `LoginPresenter` implement some interface?

Comment: Yes, it extends base class that implements interface:

`class LoginPresenter(private var loginAccountUseCase: LoginAccountUseCase,
                     private var loginAnonymousUseCase: LoginAnonymousUseCase) : BasePresenter<LoginView>() {}`
  


`open class BasePresenter<V : View> : Presenter<V>{}`

Comment: And you define in your module and inject in your activity the actual implementation? There is a common error when trying to inject the interface, but your code looks fine, unless you modified it for this question

Comment: Yes, I am injecting actual implementation. I have modfied my comment because I had problems with code formating... I looks like this problem occured only on my side :/ Maybe kapt plugin has bug?

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing the same error.